# OR in .Replace() C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have string came  from back end that in which I need to replace some value

I do this like this `usr_.avatar_base64.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "")`

But sometimes it has `data:image/jpg;base64,` so Can make some kind of OR in Replace to handle different variants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just chain another replace:

```
usr_.avatar_base64.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "")
                  .Replace("data:image/jpg;base64,", "")
```

Comment: Hm, but if first replace will do the trick, second will not works?

Comment: @EugeneSukh what do you mean?

Comment: If row contains `data:image/jpeg;base64` first replace will replace this stuff, but second will not works, yes?

Comment: @EugeneSukh If the first call to `Replace()` does not find a match, then the second call will and vice versa. `Replace()` doesn't throw an exception if no matches are found, so it's perfectly find to chain them in this manner.

Comment: @EugeneSukh, the second doing nothing in that situation is not the same as it not working.

Comment: Yeah. It helps. Thnks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
var output = base64.Contains("data:image/jpeg;base64") ? 
base64.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "") : 
base64.Replace("data:image/jpg;base64,", "") ;
```

Comment: In practice yea :P

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect scenario for RegEx.

```
Regex.Replace(usr_.avatar_base64, "data:image/jpe?g;base64", "");
```

The `?` denotes an optional character, so this will match `jpeg` and `jpg`.

See the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: This is definitely not the PERFECT scenario for RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

The data can be in other formats too, so just get everything after the comma :

```
string base64 = usr_.avatar_base64.Split(',').Last();
```